# Problems resizing UIImage, got empty image always

Tags: ios, resize, uiimage

I used the very simple way.
I create a bitmap based image context and draw the image scaled.
But I always get empty images.

```
- (UIImage *)resizeImage:(UIImage *)image to:(CGSize)newSize
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 1.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage * scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return scaledImage;
}
```

Any hint where was wrong?
I try to change the coordinate system. It still does not work.

```
CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.0, newSize.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0, -1.0);
```

Comment: You could get some ideas about resizing and transforming images from [this UIImage category](https://github.com/H2CO3/UIImage-Editor/blob/master/UIImage%2BResize.m).

Comment: refer to http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/HandlingImages/Images.html